# Webview OnProgressChanged and progressbar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In a Xamarin application I have a `CustomWebView` renderer; I'm injecting in the view and displaying a progressbar in `OnProgressChanged` event of the `WebChromeClient` with the following code.

Init:

```
    var progressBar = new Android.Widget.ProgressBar(_context, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleHorizontal);

    Control.SetWebViewClient(new CusWebViewClient($"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));

    Control.SetWebChromeClient(new CusWebChromeClient(progressBar));

    Control.AddView(progressBar);
```

CusWebChromeClient:

```
public class CusWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    Android.Widget.ProgressBar progressBar;

    public CusWebChromeClient(Android.Widget.ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    public override void OnProgressChanged(Android.Webkit.WebView view, int newProgress)
    {
        if (newProgress < 100 && progressBar.Visibility == ViewStates.Gone)
        {
            progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }

        progressBar.SetProgress(newProgress, true);

        if (newProgress == 100)
        {
            //progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the progress bar is displayed really small like:

[image]

I need to display it with full display width and with a more heigth.

Comment: Confirm with you, do you want to do the renderer with progressBar on WebView or WebChromeClient?

Comment: I need it in a WebChromeClient event because I have the event there

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT do you have other solutions on this?

Comment: I try to reproduce with the code segment you provided, but i still need more information. Could you provide the code sample on GitHub for me to test?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT you can check it here: https://github.com/IrvinDominin/HybridWebview.Xamarin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to set the width of progress bar.

You could use the screen width to set the progress bar in custom renderer. After that, it would be okay.

```
var width = (int)Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
```

Please note, 'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'Android.App.Application' and 'Xamarin.Forms.Application'. You could add reference like below to fix it.

```
using Application = Xamarin.Forms.Application;
```

**Change:**

```
Control.AddView(progressBar);
```

**To:**

```
Control.AddView(progressBar, width, 30);
```

[image]

Comment: For me still width of processbar is just less than half with above code. How can I make it full screen?